# i915 Onboard graphics not powering on when monitor is not connected

Tags: boot, 20.04, grub2, graphics, acpi

I am currently running Ubuntu 20.04 and when I do not have a monitor plugged in to the display port on my machine it never powers on the graphics.  Based on what I'm seeing in dmesg it looks like this could be caused by ACPI not powering it on.

The computer has onboard i915 graphics.

Working dmesg output:

```
[    0.011703] ACPI: FPDT 0x00000000CBBC2000 000044 (v01 INTEL  CFL      20170001 INTL 20160422)
[    0.011707] ACPI: BGRT 0x00000000CBBC1000 000038 (v01 INTEL  CFL      20170001 INTL 20160422)
[    0.011710] ACPI: Reserving FACP table memory at [mem 0xcbc08000-0xcbc08113]
```

Not working dmesg output:

```
[    0.011703] ACPI: FPDT 0x00000000CBBC2000 000044 (v01 INTEL  CFL      20170001 INTL 20160422)
[    0.011706] ACPI: Reserving FACP table memory at [mem 0xcbc08000-0xcbc08113]
```

I can recreate this by plugging/unplugging the monitor.  Unplugged the "ACPI: BGRT" line is missing.  /dev/fb0 also disappears whenever the monitor is not plugged in.

I'm trying to force the onboard graphics to power on even if nothing is plugged into it.  Is there a way to do this or an ACPI option for GRUB or Ubuntu that would do this?  I've tried turning ACPI off but that did not work.

Our remote control software does not work without /dev/fb0 which disappears when the onboard graphics are not powered on due to a monitor not being plugged in.

Comment: what do you need the onboard graphics on for? this very much sounds like an X/Y problem

Comment: Need the onboard graphics for our remote control software to work.

Comment: I ran into this issue myself a while back with an Intel NUC when trying to use remote access. If no monitor was connected, there was no video output on the remote connection. I found some somewhat sketchy workarounds for Linux, but I think a better option might be to try an Extended Display Identification Data (EDID) emulator into a graphics port to fool the machine into thinking a display is hooked up. Take a look at Fit-Headless, VGA Dummy, and Dr. HDMI for options. Last time I looked they were inexpensive...

Comment: These are the HP equivalent of an Intel NUC. 

Hardware solutions probably wont work due to the quantities and geographic area these units cover. 

What kind of sketchy solutions?